# Can't correct the error in this basic WCF Service hosted in a Console Application

Tags: wcf

I have a basic WCF Service hosted in a Console Application that I can't consume from another Console Application.

I'm studying WCF so I'm trying to make it work to follow along with a book.

When I try to consume the service I get the following error

```
Unhandled Exception: System.ServiceModel.EndpointNotFoundException: There was no endpoint listening at http://localhost:6599/HostCmdLineApp/HelloWorldService.svc/HelloWorldService that could accept the message. This is often caused by an incorrect address or SOAP action...
```

But the service runs well:

[image]

I'm using VS2012.

The general structure of the solution is:

[image]

```
<system.serviceModel>
    <services>
        <service name="MyWCFServices.HelloWorldService"
                 behaviorConfiguration="HelloWorldServiceBehavior">
            <endpoint address="HelloWorldService"
                      binding="basicHttpBinding"
                      contract="MyWCFServices.IHelloWorldService" />

            <endpoint address="mex"
                      binding="mexHttpBinding"
                      contract="IMetadataExchange" />
        </service>
    </services>
    <behaviors>
        <serviceBehaviors>
            <behavior name="HelloWorldServiceBehavior">
                <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true"/>
            </behavior>
        </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
</system.serviceModel>
```

The Main method that publishes the service from HostCmdLineApp is:

```
static void Main(string[] args) {
   var baseAddress = new Uri("http://localhost:6599/HostCmdLineApp/HelloWorldService.svc");
   using (var host = new ServiceHost(typeof(MyWCFServices.HelloWorldService), baseAddress)) {
       host.Open();
       Console.WriteLine("HelloWorldService is ready to be used. ");
       Console.WriteLine("Press <ENTER> to terminate service.");
       Console.ReadKey();
       host.Close();
   }
}
```

The App.config file of HelloWorldClient (the service consumer) was generated by the SvcUtil tool:

```
<system.serviceModel>
    <bindings>
        <basicHttpBinding>
            <binding name="BasicHttpBinding_IHelloWorldService" />
        </basicHttpBinding>
    </bindings>
    <client>
        <endpoint address="http://localhost:6599/HostCmdLineApp/HelloWorldService.svc 
                                                                            HelloWorldService"
            binding="basicHttpBinding" 
            bindingConfiguration="BasicHttpBinding_IHelloWorldService"
            contract="IHelloWorldService" name="BasicHttpBinding_IHelloWorldService" />
    </client>
</system.serviceModel>
```

And the Main method that consumes the service is:

```
    static void Main(string[] args) {
        var client = new HelloWorldServiceClient();
        Console.WriteLine(client.GetMessage("Rafael Soteldo"));
    }
```

I ran VS as Administrator.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your client address is incorrect. There is a forward slash after svc.

```
address="http://localhost:6599/HostCmdLineApp/HelloWorldService.svc/HelloWorldService"
```

If you leave your address blank on the service host then you would not need the "/HelloWorldService" at the end.

Comment: Sorry, the slash was in the address, but I somehow deleted it when I edited the question. What do you mean with letting the address blank? The definition of the endpoint forces me to specify address, binding, contract.

Comment: I now know what the problem is. I have to run the service first and then run the client. I thought that I had configured the solution's StartUp to do it in that order. But it was not correct. Thank you for answering. According to the question I did, your answer is correct